# Probability and stuff

Tags: probability

If the probality that Sam studies for a test and passes the test is .75. and the probability that he studies for the test is .6. What is the probability the Sam passes the test, given that he studies for it.

Comment: Show some personal input and stuff.

Comment: Think about the formula for conditional probability.

Comment: $P(A\cap B) = P(A) \cdot P(B\mid A)$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: Draw a tree of possible outcomes.

[image]

The path of known probability $0.75$ is highlighted in red. The conditional probability you are after is denoted $p$.

Comment: Finally, what is the answer ?. It must be a number.

Comment: No kidding, but finding it rests with you. Happy New Year and best of luck in your endeavors.

Comment: Indeed I'm worry for many M.SE past and new readers. It's my custom to point out quite clearly an answer to a question at the very end of any of my answers. In that way, any person who doesn't like to follow the argument can find the answer. In M.SE there are too many pretty long answer that fail to point out what is "THE ANSWER" at the very end. Thanks. Happy new year 2015 for you too.